# TortoiseSVN Repo-Browser with DisplayLink workaround

Tags: tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN's Repo Browser crashes DisplayLink consistently.  Does anyone know of a workaround for this or alternative SVN clients?  I have latest versions of both.

Comment: I have versions: 
- TortoiseSVN: v. 1.9.7
- DisplayLink:
Software Package: DisplayLink Graphics
Software Package Version: 8.2.2210.0
Software Package Date: 23rd June 2017

DisplayLink Ethernet Driver Version: 8.2.1629.0
DisplayLink Audio Driver Version: 8.2.1638.0

Windows 10 Build 14393 onwards:
 - DisplayLink Graphics Driver Version: 8.2.2139.0
 - DisplayLink Graphics Driver Date: 20th June 2017

Answer (score 1):

because of you're version of Windows and DisplayLink driver in use, the driver doesn't see what application is running or how it is running. I wish I could have commented to get the details, but I don't have enough points to, yet.

Like for any crash, I suggest you collect the crash data and send it for analysis. [DisplayLink has a Customer Support Tool](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/533818) collecting memory dumps and, they can analyse the stack to see.

Your configuration, with identical version numbers, has been reproduced but not the crash. DisplayLink uses TortoiseSVN internally.